# Issue with pagers while Repeating Repeaters

Tags: xpages

I am using the current newest ExtLibs, and a Domino 9.0.1 Server with FP3.

I am trying set up my own multi level categorized view with repeat controls that are getting data from an SQLite Database, and I am hitting a snag with the pager controls.

***Structure***

1. I have a primary Repeat Control that displays 5 categories at a time (Sections).  This is connected to the primary pager.
2. Inside this repeat control, I have a panel that has another repeat control for the actual data. (In some cases I put another section to create multiple levels with another repeater...)

*** The problem**

When I have multiple pages on the primary repeater and I start out at page one, then in one embedded pager, I select page 2, then I select a different page on the primary pager, then all embedded pagers are automatically reset to page 2. It seems to me as though the request scope variable that controls the embedded pager number is shared among all repeated instances.

What is the best way to go about solving this problem? And am I barking up the wrong tree by repeating repeaters to begin with?

******************************************* Stand alone XPage for reproduction

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
        id="pager1" for="repeat1" panelPosition="left">
    </xp:pager>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="5" var="primaryList">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var list:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
list.add("1")
list.add("2")
list.add("3")
list.add("4")
list.add("5")
list.add("6")
list.add("7")
list.add("8")
list.add("9")
list.add("10")
list.add("11")
list.add("12")
list.add("13")
list.add("14")
list.add("15")
list.add("16")
list.add("17")
list.add("18")
return list;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:section id="section1" header="#{javascript:primaryList}">
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:panel style="padding:0px 0px 5px 40px">
                <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next"
                    partialRefresh="true" id="pager2" for="repeat2"
                    panelPosition="left">
                </xp:pager>
                <xp:br></xp:br>
                <xp:br></xp:br>
                <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="5" var="innerRepeat">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var list:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
list.add("1")
list.add("2")
list.add("3")
list.add("4")
list.add("5")
list.add("6")
list.add("7")
list.add("8")
list.add("9")
list.add("10")
list.add("11")
list.add("12")
list.add("13")
list.add("14")
list.add("15")
list.add("16")
list.add("17")
list.add("18")
return list;}]]></xp:this.value>
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                        value="#{javascript:innerRepeat.toString();}">
                    </xp:inputText>
                    <xp:br></xp:br>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xp:panel></xp:section>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

**steps to reproduce**

1. be on page one on primary pager.
2. in any sub pager, select page 2.
3. Notice correctness of other pagers
4. Switch main pager to page 3
5. Notice all sub pagers on on page 2

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug. It's working as designed (!)...

The problem is that the repeat does not create multiple pagers inside for each iteration. So there is basically only one pager and that pager keeps only one PagerState. That's why they are acting weird.

When you use `repeatControls="true"` option, repeat will not iterate only one component, instead it will really create multiple components for each iteration. However, in that case, you can't use Pager component for such a repeat, because the new repeat component does not have an iterator anymore. It will not be able to find 'pagination' and will throw '*division of zero*' error.

Here, I have explained the difference between two modes of Repeat component (from slide #36):

https://speakerdeck.com/sbasegmez/engage-2015-10-mistakes-you-and-every-xpages-developer-make-yes-i-said-you?slide=36

The solution would be creating your own pager design for inner repeats.

Update:

Another approach is marking the outer Repeat as `repeatControls="true"` and removing the outer pager. In such a configuration you'll have multiple pager components in the component tree but you have to sacrifice the outer pager. In this configuration, you'll need to load all elements in the outer repeat (because they can't be actively manipulated anymore).

To mimic the pager behaviour you can design a custom pager and use `rendered` attribute for inner repeats. It will slow the page down, but will provide 'paging' feeling to the user.

Comment: If I am unsure how many primary categories there are, how can I ensure that all elements are presented?

Comment: For the outer repeat, you can't control how many pages to be displayed dynamically. One option; you can use query parameters and reload the page every time you switch pages (e.g. `page.xsp?from=1&count=5`). You will actually mimic the pager component but switch to a new page every time.

Comment: In this way, basically you will display the first five initially. If you have more than five categories, you might display a 'Next' link (like a pager) which navigates to the next set of categories. The key is, you need to reload the page to see the next five categories. Pager, on the other hand, use a view-scoped mechanism to keep track of where you are. `repeatControls="true"` does not allow run-time changes in the component list.

Comment: Alright.  thanks.  I am going to have to give this a try.  Too bad that these controls do not permit this sort of a design out of the box.